# Copying specific table rows from one database source to another

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy specific rows from a table on one database to another using C#. I tried the following using the `DataAdapter.Update(DataSet)` functionality:

```
using (OleDbConnection sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(source)){
        using (OleDbConnection destinationConnection = new OleDbConnection(destination))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();
            destinationConnection.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter1.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", sourceConnection);
            adapter1.Fill(dataSet);

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter2.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", destinationConnection);
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter2);
            adapter2.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter2.Update(dataSet);

            sourceConnection.Close();
            destinationConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: the adapter.update() work when there is/are changed in datatable's data

Comment: But there are changes. The rows in the source table are different then the rows in the destination table. @MarioWu

Comment: Sorry,  I am talking about the datatable in your dataadapter. fill(dataset).  The dataadapter. update()  work like this: everytime you make change  on a datatable,  it will write it to the change state,  what changed,  what added,  and what had been removed.  When you call dataadapter. update(),  it will base on this datatable change state to generate query to manipulate data in databases.  If you get data from 1 database,  make some changes on datatable,  call datatable.acceptchanges(), then update,  you changed data will not be written to the DB because that . acceptchanges()  clear the cha

Comment: clear the change state,  the same thing happen on your situation,  no data changed record - > no update